# How to set up ReportsAnywhere to connect to MongoDB?

Tags: jdbc, mongodb, driver, report

Supposedly [ReportsAnywhere](http://www.reportsanywhere.com/) will talk with MongoDB to generate reports.  I am not sure if it is using the [JDBC driver](https://github.com/erh/mongo-jdbc) or a different method.  Hoping someone can help me on how to set up reports anywhere database driver/connection to mongodb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the ReportsAnywhere author makes mention of building such a product [here](http://www.reportsanywhere.com/pebble/2010/04/16/1271437740000.html). Based on his description, this is no using a JDBC driver but pulling data via the native driver.

It looks like he did a presentation at [MongoBerlin](http://www.10gen.com/conferences/mongoberlin2010) in October 2010, unfortunately, I cannot any videos / slides from the presentation. The website is also completely devoid of examples.

Given that ReportsAnywhere is a paid-for product and this is an advertised feature, your best bet may be to go directly to ReportsAnywhere. Maybe you'll get lucky on SO, but I would definitely contact their team directly. Looks like Hans, the creator, is also available [on twitter](http://twitter.com/reportsanywhere).

Comment: Thanks, I will try contacting them - also I thought ReportsAnywhere is a "Free open-source
reporting tool and document generator."  - at least per their web site.

Comment: You're right, it is a FOSS product, but they definitely charge for support: http://www.reportsanywhere.com/support.html. Based on your questions, you're looking for a reporting solution for MongoDB. You may also want to check out JasperSoft. It looks like they have some activity on that front: http://www.jaspersoft.com/bigdata